# Setting a date to the Monday of that week in a trigger in SQL

Tags: sql, date, plsql, triggers

Hi I'm using sqldeveloper connected to an oracle server. I'm trying to change the date to the monday of that week in a trigger but it says `Warning: execution completed with warning`, can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_week_menu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF week_start ON week_menu FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF DATEPART(dw, :NEW.week_start) != 1 THEN
    SELECT DATEADD(ww, DATEDIFF(ww, 0, :NEW.week_start), 0)
    INTO :NEW.week_start
    FROM sys.dual;
  END IF;
END;
```

Thanks in advance! =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably because `datediff` and `dateadd` are SQL-Server functions, not Oracle.

From what I understand you're trying to do this should work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_week_menu
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF week_start ON week_menu FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF to_char(:new.week_start,'d') <> 1 THEN
      :new.week_start := next_day( :new.week_start - 7
                                 , 'MONDAY' );
   END IF;
END;
/
```

But in case I don't understand what you're trying to do. There's a [number of date functions](http://psoug.org/reference/date_func.html) in Oracle that you should probably be aware of.